# Conditional probability gone over 1?

Tags: probability

I have the following system:

[image]

Each leg has $0.8$ chance to be closed(and to allow the electricity to transfer).
It is known that in B at least one leg is open, what is the probability that electiricty will transfer from X to Y?

What I have done is to find the chance that at least 1 leg will be open in B is $P(W)=1-(0.8)^3=0.488$

The chance that B will transfer electricity and that at least 1 leg will be open in B is $P(W\cap U)=1-(0.2)^2=0.96$

So $P(U\mid W)=\dfrac{P(W \cap U)}{P(W)}=\dfrac{0.96}{0.488}>1$

What have I done wrong?

[Note: I'm just trying to find the chance of B to transfer electricity for first]

Comment: Assuming that $p_i$ is the event that the $i^{th}$ path is open (and that these are independent) then the numerator should be $P(p_1\cap p_2)=P(p_1)\times P(p_2)$.

Comment: @lulu you mean $0.2*02 = 0.04$ as the numerator? I didn't understand why since $0.04 / 0.488 = 0.081$ which is extremely low chance for B to transfer electricity although with 80% chance to transfer electricity for each leg I expect the total chance to be higher than that (I have 1 or 2 legs each with 80% chance to do that)

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand what $p_i$ means (after all, you never defined it).  The way I read the problem:  $p_i$ is the event that the $i^{th}$ path is open.  Thus $P(p_i)=.2$ .  Your fraction becomes $\frac {P(p_1)\times P(p_2)}{P(p_2)}=P(p_1)=.2$.  Regardless, you should edit the question to clearly define your terms.

Comment: Side note:  I see that the posted solution has a completely different read on what $p_i$ means.  It's likely enough that my guess was wrong...but we shouldn't have to guess!

Comment: @lulu sorry since the A and B was "kind of" taken I tried to find different letters but now I've edited it

Comment: If $S\subseteq T$ then $P(S)\leq P(T)$, so it can't be possible for $P(W\cap U)>P(W)$.

Comment: What $1-(0.2)^2$ calculates is the conditional probability that at least one leg is closed when given that one *specific* leg is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1-0.2^2$ is the conditional probability that electricity flows through B when given that a *specific* leg is open.  That is not what you wanted.

The probability of "transferring electricity through B and *at least* one leg of B is open" is: $$\mathsf P(p_1\cap p_2)~=~3(0.2)^2(0.8)+3(0.2)(0.8)^2 ~=~ 0.48$$

Alternatively $$\mathsf P(p_1\cap p_2)~=~1-(0.2)^3-(0.8)^3 ~=~ 0.48$$

It is the probability at least one leg is open and at least one leg is closed.

(Research topic: "Binomial Distribution")

Thus: $$\mathsf P(p_1\mid p_2) = \frac{0.48}{0.488} ~\approx~0.98{\small 36\ldots}$$

Comment: How did you calculate $P(p_1\cap p_2)$ if at least 1 leg is open the only way to transfer electricity is either that we have 2 legs left (1 is given as open) so its $1-(0.2)^2=0.96$ (all the cases less the case in which 2 legs left are open)  or the case (its a new case I didnt think about last time) that 2 legs are given as open so we have only 1 leg left with $0.8$ chance to be closed. so together its $0.96 + 0.86 - 0.96*0.86=0.9944$

Comment: @TheOne That is the conditional probability that at least one leg is closed given that one specific leg is open.  You wanted the probability that at least one leg is open and at least one leg is closed.

Comment: I see it makes sense, what is the first formula you used? as far as I can tell the 2nd case you did: "all the cases less the (case that all are open or the case that all are closed)" right? and because they can't occur together you just summed them up instead of subtracting their intersection later?

Comment: @TheOne Essentially, yes.  Let $B$ be the count of open legs.  $$\begin{align}P(p_1\cap p_2) =& P(B\neq 0\cap B\neq 3) \\=& 1-P(B=0\cup B=3) \\=& 1-(0.2^3+0.8^3) \\=& 0.48\\ =& 3(0.8)(0.2)^2+3(0.8)^2(0.2) \\=& P(B=1\cup B=2)\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks, the "or" formula is Cumulative distribution function? trying to find it since it looks so familiar to something I learnt many many years ago though I can't remember the full formula

Comment: @TheOne It is from the binomial expansion: $(0.2+0.8)^3 = (0.2)^3+3(0.2)^2(0.8)+3(0.2)(0.8)^2+(0.8)^3 = 1$  For further details research the suggested topic: "Binomial Distribution"

Comment: Thanks, there is only one thing that worries me now, I have seen that the chance of element A to transfer electricity is $1-(0.2)^2=0.96$ which is kind of weird that the chance of B given that 1 (or more) of his legs are open to transfer electricity is $0.983$ because B is just like A or even worse(if 2 legs are open), isn't it weird(I expect B to have lower chance than A)?

Comment: It is counterintuitive, yes, but I don't find counterintuitive things weird because they actually happen quite often (particularly in probability calculations).